# column \"Id\" violates not-null constraint"

Tags: c#, postgresql

I just started today with PostgreSQL and created a `Person` table in my demo database and trying to connect to the database with C# . Database connection is made successfully but I face null value error for `Id` column even though I am clearly passing it. Here is my code:

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var db = new DB();

        var person = new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Stevie" };
        db.Persons.Add(person);
        db.SaveChanges();

        var persons = db.Persons;
        foreach (var p in persons)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class DB : DbContext
{
    public DB() : base(nameOrConnectionString: "Test") { }
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

[Table("Person", Schema = "public")]
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Person Table SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE public."Person"
 (
"Id" integer NOT NULL,
"Name" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
CONSTRAINT "Person_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
 );
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful to see the table definition as well.

Comment: @TiesonT. Please check now

Comment: you're taggin both `mysql` and `postgresql`. You should remove one of them just to avoid confusions.

Comment: Hmm does you exception rise during insert or during iteration? My guess is that Postgree isn't as nice as SQL Server about Identity (auto generated key columns) and EF probably expects Id to be generated by database so it does not send it - yet database expets Id to be given by query. There is probably some other type of column that need to be used.

Comment: I do not know postgresql, but when I have problems with EF and MS SQL, I like to view the operation with Profiler.  This way I get to see the actual SQL statement(s) that get generated by EF.  This often leads me to the solution.   I see from a web search that postgresql has a "log_statement" feature that might help.

Comment: This is basically a guess, but I think the code first provider for Postgres might be assuming that a [Key] column is database generated.
Try specfying `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` for the Id column?

Comment: @gnud You made a guess , and that guess is guessed Perfectly .. Thanks it works

Comment: @AhsanAttari Great! If you are going to be inserting data, though, you probably _want_ the database to generate the Id. You can do that by removing that attribute, and by changing the column type in the database to a SERIAL instead of an INT.

Comment: Thanks Man !!!! I was also searching this ... Really appreciated

Comment: On second thought, instead of removing the attribute, change it to `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`, in case  you switch to a different database later :)